# what would be an elegant way to implement this design in scss?

Tags: html, css, sass, less

I've created a display widget in html and I'm trying to figure out an elegant way to style it. Here's a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fbwu9aoc/3/

I tried to encapsulate a few of the styles with meaningful class names like:

```
.moreThanMinus100
{
    background-color:darkgray;
    display:table-cell;
    width:50px;
    line-height:10px;
    border:2px solid lightgrey;
}
```

but the css definitions aren't getting applied.  This jsfiddle also represents just a partial extract of css.  I'm sure that there's a much more elegant way to implement the css for this widget, especially with the use of scss.  Are there any scss pros who can help shed some light on this?

Answer (score 2):

Ids are selected with `#` and class names are selected with `.`

For your element

```
<div id="moreThanPlus100">&nbsp;</div>
```

either change to

```
<div class="moreThanPlus100">&nbsp;</div>
```

or change your css to

```
#moreThanPlus100
{
    background-color:darkgreen;
    display:table-cell;
    width:50px;
    line-height:10px;
    border:2px solid lightgrey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit based on comments:**

**[Codepen Scss fiddle link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JWMjyQ)**

Scss Structure Snippet:

```
#VarianceColorKey {
    width: 370px;
    display: table;
    .common {
        display: table-cell;
        line-height: 10px;
        border-color: lightgrey;
        border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    }
    .tableRow {
        display: table-row;
        .moreThanMinus100 {
            background-color: #57595b;
            width: 55px;
        }
        .lessThanMinus100 {
            background-color: #939599;
            width: 110px;
            border-left-width: 0px;
            border-right-width: 0px;
        }
        .noChange {
            background-color: white;
            width: 55px;
        }
        .lessThanPlus100 {
            background-color: #a5c036;
            width: 110px;
            border-left-width: 0px;
            border-right-width: 0px;
        }
        .moreThanPlus100 {
            background-color: #586a30;
            width: 55px;
        }
        .tableCell {
            display: table-cell;
        }
        .textRight {
            text-align: right;
        }
        .textLeft {
            text-align: left;
        }
        .textCenter {
            text-align: center;
        }
    }
    .tr1 {
        line-height: 30px;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .tr2 {
        line-height: 10px;
    }
    .tr3 {
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    .tr4 {
        line-height: 12px;
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    .textRight {
        text-align: right;
    }
    .textLeft {
        text-align: left;
    }
    .textCenter {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

- This has nothing to do with Sass, at least bearing by the shared
  code.
- Note that `#` is used for IDs, which are unique, so in this case if you wish to impact many html elements with the same CSS properties, classes would be best (they are declared with a dot before it's name `.class`).
- Below there is a suggested polish placing most styles in your stylesheet and avoiding embedding them into your html, leaving the latter much more readable/editable.
- By using classes you are able to impact many html elements with the
  same class (like `.common` or `.tableCell`) avoiding repeating the
  same properties in other classes.

```css
.ColorKeySpectrumWidget {
  width: 370px;
  display: table;
  border: 2px;
}

.common {
  display: table-cell;
  line-height: 10px;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
}

.tableRow {
  display: table-row;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.tableRow2 {
  line-height: 10px;
  display: table-row;
}

.tableRow3 {
  display: table-row;
  font-size: 2px;
}

.tableRow4 {
  display: table-row;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.tableCell {
  display: table-cell;
}

.textRight {
  text-align: right;
}

.textLeft {
  text-align: left;
}

.textCenter {
  text-align: center;
}

.moreThanMinus100 {
  background-color: darkgray;
  width: 50px;
}

.lessThanMinus100 {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 100px;
}

.noChange {
  background-color: white;
  width: 50px;
}

.lessThanPlus100 {
  background-color: limegreen;
  width: 100px;
}

.moreThanPlus100 {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ColorKeySpectrumWidget">
  <div class="tableRow">
    <div class="tableCell"></div>
    <div class="tableCell textLeft">Decrease</div>
    <div class="tableCell"></div>
    <div class="tableCell textRight">Increase</div>
    <div class="tableCell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tableRow2">
    <!-- color key -->
    <div class="common moreThanMinus100">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="common lessThanMinus100">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="common noChange">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="common lessThanPlus100">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="common moreThanPlus100">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tableRow3">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="tableRow4 textCenter">
    <div class="tableCell">More than</div>
    <div class="tableCell"></div>
    <div class="tableCell textCenter">No</div>
    <div class="tableCell"></div>
    <div class="tableCell">More than</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tableRow4">
    <div class="tableCell textRight">-100%</div>
    <div class="tableCell"></div>
    <div class="tableCell textCenter">change</div>
    <div class="tableCell"></div>
    <div class="tableCell">+100%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks syden.  the code you provided is a great update. is there a way to nest this css? for example, let's say another css file gets loaded on the page which has a css class of .tableRow.  I would want to avoid a collision between the tableRow css used for my ColorKeySpectrumWidget and the tableRow css defined in the other css file.

Comment: You can nest with Sass: http://sass-lang.com - But in that specific case you mention, the CSS that will be impacting is either the one loaded last or the one with more specificity (example .class1 vs body div .class1), the latter will override the first since it has a deeper selector.

Comment: You can put multiple selectors in a style to prevent clashing. Example, instead of '.moreThanPlus100' you can do '.ColorKeySpectrumWidget .moreThanPlus100'

Comment: this would be a more ideal sass structure for me based on my object-oriented programming background: https://jsfiddle.net/r4gsj52q/. can you post an update to snyden's example to reflect a proper sass implementation based on the more ideal structure I have in mind? feel free to optimize even further if you have greater insight or see additional opportunities.

Comment: @syden thanks for all your help. I just tried the latest iteration you posted. Your original implementation works:

.tableRow1{ display: table-row; line-height: 30px; font-size:16px;      font-weight: bold }

but the new implementation does not seem to work:

.tableRow{ display: table-row; .tr1 { line-height: 30px;font-size:16px;         font-weight: bold;}}

only 'display: table-row' gets applied.  font-weight:bold does not get applied, for example.  I'm referencing the css as class="tableRow tr1" in the tr

Comment: @syden - I tried the html/css combo on codepen.io like u suggested and tried it with the scss pre-processor as well as the sass pre-processor but the 'tableRow tr(x)' css class approach does not appear to be working:https://codepen.io/ac123/pen/gmXJwy. does something need to be tweaked?

Comment: @user7571529, added tweaks above.

Comment: You are welcome, if it helped you please consider either up voting/marking the answer as correct or both, it will help me, thank you. Regards.